# How to keep an excel file open in sharepoint or onedrive after I log out?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, sharepoint

I have an excel file that contains some vba scripts that refreshes other excel files at specific intervals. My problem is this file must be open in order to have that macro run. My question is how can I open this excel file so that it stays open almost forever even after I log off. something like nohup or start utility. Due to some security considerations I don't have the permission to use external vbs scripts and Windows scheduler to run them instead of this excel file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are running Windows Server, the simplest solution is not to logoff. Just run Excel under a separate user account and switch away from it, to do your work under another user account.

Comment: @harrymc thanks, this seems like a good solution. My files reside on sharepoint, so wondering if sharepoint has such a facility to refresh excel files (connected to external data sources) automatically without the need to open them.

Answer (score 0):

When opening an Excel workbook that's saved on SharePoint in the browser,
you can't run macros, and this is
[by design](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Differences-between-using-a-workbook-in-the-browser-and-in-Excel-f0dc28ed-b85d-4e1d-be6d-5878005db3b6).
You will have to open the workbook using Excel installed on your local machine
to run any macros.

If you are running Windows Server, the simplest solution is not to logoff.
Just run Excel under a separate user account and switch away from it,
to do your work under another user account. A password requirement on switching
user sessions will be enough as protection.